# ActiveAndroid - How to save data into Android database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite, activeandroid

I have an Android app in which I'm getting data from an API. Now I need to save this data from the API into an `ActiveAndroid` table.

So I've got stuck on that part.

Here is my table Partners(Active Android):

```
@Table(name = "Partners")
public class Partners extends Model {

    @Column(name = "Name")
    public String name;

    public Partners() {}

    public Partners(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

This is my POJO model:

```
public class Partner {

    @Expose
    @Column(name = "name")
    private List<String> name;


    public List<String> getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(List<String> name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And here is part of code where I'm getting data and trying to save it into `ActiveAndroid` table:

```
public class DownloadMain extends Fragment implements Callback<Partner> {

    private static final String TAG = DownloadMain.class.getSimpleName();

    private Button dloadPartners;
    private Call callPartners;

    public DownloadMain() {}

    public DownloadMain newInstance() { return new DownloadMain(); }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.download_main, container, false);

        dloadPartners = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.downloadPartners);
        dloadPartners.setOnClickListener(btnListener);

        callPartners = APIHelper.getApiService().getPartners();

        return view;
    }

    Button.OnClickListener btnListener = (new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            callPartners.clone().enqueue(DownloadMain.this);
            insertPartners();
        }
    });

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {

        if(response.body() == null) {
            try {
                response.errorBody().string();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Partners!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            List<String> partners = (List<String>) response.body();
            Log.d(TAG, "Number of partners received: " + partners.size());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Partners downloaded!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
    }

    private void insertPartners() {
        ActiveAndroid.beginTransaction();
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                Partner partner = new Partner();
                partner.getName();
                //partner.save();
            }
            ActiveAndroid.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } finally {
            ActiveAndroid.endTransaction();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is how to save data I get from the API into table, so I need few tips and advice how to properly do that.

**Question: I need some tips how to save data I get from web with retrofit into `ActiveAndroid` table?**

Answer (score 1):

please check my old weather app project, where I'f already used `ActiveAndroid`.

Here's one of my saving to database methods:

> ```
> public void saveCityDataToDatabase(Forecast forecast) {
>     ActiveAndroid.beginTransaction();
>     try {
>         if (WeatherApplication.getCityList().size() > 0) {
>             new Delete().from(City.class).execute();
>         }
>         forecast.getCity().getCoord().save();
>         forecast.getCity().save();
>         ActiveAndroid.setTransactionSuccessful();
>     } finally {
>         ActiveAndroid.endTransaction();
>     }
>     Log.d("DATABASE", "WeatherApplication: " + WeatherApplication.getCityList());
> } }
> ```
>
> From: https://github.com/piotrek1543/LocalWeather/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/piotr/localweather/repositories/WeatherDatabaseRepository.java

With `ActiveAndroid` is really easy to save Objects like `Weather` or `Wind`, but for some purposes you would need to use `TypeSerializer`. In your example you would use it to deserialize and save `List<String>`.

As you may notice from its Github page: https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid
this libary is not maintained more than two years, so I can say clearly that is deprecated and not good to use to fresh projects. It may have many bugs. For me, implementation of this lib was a pretty painful.

Instead of `ActiveAndroid`, I would recommend you to use [`Realm`](https://github.com/realm/realm-java), [`greenDao`](https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO) or [`ORMLite`](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-android) library to store your data.

Hope it would help

Answer (score 0):

First of all create a parameterless constructor and call super in it.

```
public Partners() {
    super();
}
```

then a partern.save() should suffice.

To retreive all the parterns you could do something like

```
List<Partner> partners = new Select().from(Partner.class).execute());
```

if you get the Partner object fro web via retrofit, probably you are using Gson to put the json in partner object. so you can make that object extending model, put a paramterless constructor like above and put a `@Table` annotation.